# Unsure how to correctly edit my AndroidManifest.xml when creating a new class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I'm currently building my first Android app using Java. I am trying to add a class to my app called Pop.java that displays a pop up message. However, when compiling its telling me my configuration is incorrect and I am getting an "AndroidManifest.xml does exist of has incorrect root tag" error. When looking it up it seems like I need to update my .xml file to add this .Pop class. Here is what I'm trying right now thats still giving me errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<activity xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.hungry15">

    <activity
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        </activity> android:name=".Pop" ></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The only part I edited of this .xml file was

```
</activity> android:name=".Pop" ></activity>
```

Any help on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two Tags are wrong!

Open **manifest** and **application**. For each tag you open you need to close. Also New Activities live inside application tag.

Also you are opening a new tag for activity wrongly

```
</activity> android:name=".Pop" ></activity>
```

Should be

```
<activity android:name=".Pop" ></activity>
```

The Manifest fixed bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.hungry15">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Pop" ></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do some correction to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.hungry15">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Pop"/> <!--here is your activity, you wanna add!-->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```